# Hibernate cascade=save-update, updates all siblings of new child entity

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, parent-child, many-to-one

I have a parent-child configuration of hibernate as below

```
<class name="A" table="TAB_A">
  <... columns defined here ...>
  <map name="lookup" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false" fetch="join" access="field" >
     <key column="A_FK" />
     <map-key type="string" column="key_name" />
     <one-to-many class="B" />
 </class>

 <class name="B" table="TAB_B>
    <... columns defined here ...>
    <many-to-one name="a" class="A" column="A_FK" not-null="true" cascade="save-update" />
    <property name="key" column="key_name" type="string" not-null="true" />
 </class>
```

Recently we upgraded hibernate from 2.x to 4.x.

The problem we are facing after this migration is that the new insert in table B inserts the new records as well as updates all the existing records of TAB_B.

The update statement updates the "key_name" column of TAB_B.

I tried looking into the source code of Hibernate and found that the `AbstractCollectionPersister.insertRows` method is now overridden in `OneToManyPersister.insertRows`. This overridden method calls another method `writeIndex` which invokes the update statements.

So is this intended behavior? If not why the child entries are getting updated? 
Are we missing something?

- Hanumant